# How to read specific data and write to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xml.etree

I have data in xml file and I am reading 3 columns : `price , name , calories`

**xml data**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
  <row>
    <index>0</index>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</desc>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </row>
  <row>
    <index>1</index>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</desc>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </row>
  <row>
    <index>2</index>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</desc>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </row>
  <row>
    <index>3</index>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <desc>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</desc>
    <calories>600</calories>
  </row>
  <row>
    <index>4</index>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <desc>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</desc>
    <calories>950</calories>
  </row>
</data>
```

**Code :**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parse_xml = ET.parse('/content/sample_data/xyz.xml')
get_root_element = parse_xml.getroot()


for data in get_root_element.findall('row'):

  prc = data.find('price')
  nm  = data.find('name')
  cal = data.find('calories')
  temp = prc.text + ',' +  nm.text + ',' + cal.text
  print(temp)
```

The above code gives me data but need to store this data to csv file

How do I need to write logic for this. Is it possible to do with `pandas / csv`

Need to add my headers as well to that csv file

Headers : `price , name , calories`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754818/10824407) of [@kiric8494](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19134648/kiric8494) is good enough, you can stay with it. You can also implement it using [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which will be quite shorter:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from csv import DictWriter

parse_xml = ET.parse(r"/content/sample_data/xyz.xml")
root = parse_xml.getroot()
with open(r"/content/sample_data/abc.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=("price", "name", "calories"), extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows({e.tag: e.text for e in row} for row in root)
```

Basically we set up `DictWriter` to ignore all fields except `price`, `name` and `calories` and then pass generator to [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) which construct dictionary of all child nodes of `<row>` where *key is tag* and *value is text*.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution @ewz93

**I have done in following way**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

parse_xml = ET.parse('/content/sample_data/xyz.xml')
get_root_element = parse_xml.getroot()

final_data_set = [] # [ [],[],[] ]

for data in get_root_element.findall('row'):
  temp = []
  prc = data.find('price')
  nm  = data.find('name')
  cal = data.find('calories')
  temp=[prc.text + ',' +  nm.text +  ',' + cal.text]
  final_data_set.append(temp)

headers = ['price','name','calories']

with open('/content/sample_data/abc.csv','w') as wr:
  csv_wr = csv.writer(wr)
  csv_wr.writerow(headers)
  for elem in final_data_set:
    for item in elem:
      csv_wr.writerow(item.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the values in lists and create a DataFrame from that:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

parse_xml = ET.parse('/content/sample_data/xyz.xml')
get_root_element = parse_xml.getroot()

prc_list = []
nm_list = []
cal_list = []

for data in get_root_element.findall('row'):
  prc_list.append(data.find('price'))
  nm_list.append(data.find('name'))
  cal_list.append(data.find('calories'))

df = pd.DataFrame({"price": prc_list, "name": nm_list, "calories": cal_list})
df.to_excel("your_file_name.xlsx") # or if you really want a CSV use df.to_csv("your_file_name.xlsx")
```

This is probably not the prettiest solution because there is also [pandas.read_xml()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) so you probably could make it shorter and avoid having to use etree by directly reading the XML into a DataFrame and then directly write that to CSV.

Comment: Indeed. With `read_xml` a simple one-liner: `pd.read_xml("input.xml", xpath=".//row", parser="etree")[["price", "name", "calories"]].to_csv("output.csv")`